# django-rest-framework object-level conditional validation

Tags: django-rest-framework

**How to perform object-level conditional validation using django-rest-framework.**
If we use `validate(self, attrs)` in serializer, validation happens for all calls. I should know and apply it to certain http verbs. ex: I want to perform a object-level validation only for PUT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the request inside a serializer method using:

```
request = self.context['request']
```

You can then do any conditional validation using 'request.method'

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In general, do you suggest Serializer class is the right place to write business validations?